# PHP substr counts wrong

Tags: php

I want a 130 chars random string

```
$param['sec1'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(95));
$param['sec1'] = substr($param['sec1'], 0, 130);
var_dump($param['sec1']);
```

and I get the following result:

```
    string(128) "zrAND6xJVREfTA6SMfp1k9C+UDzabPMse6Awd/1Vul+2AgHLBzoOc0T/VlbQSV6dVjy38
d/3dkRDaNnG9tJjCvy3Bm/OccPKo2amJkEANTAWTvt+cPtgIZW42FWdntE=" ["zrAND6xJVREfTA6SMfp1k9C+UDzabPMse6Awd\/1Vul+2AgHLBzoOc0T\/VlbQSV6dVjy38d\/
3dkRDaNnG9tJjCvy3Bm\/OccPKo2amJkEANTAWTvt+cPtgIZW42FWdntE=","dT+w00J2fQPwst2
VKKG55cck6THLW7PIkKQReYlw4U3Q4fWJqagsxfRzrGl0fsHbjWWw9diYkqDbagJLwm0KCUVjHTC
9Rs62Tv1tdyIXNkJtc7Ba4mRbbTOZpHpeHFw=","SAbUFosDFS1KKHXAXGGtfxO09WxeqK\/rO10
9cKKtUPUA7dgn\/jC\/snRZt4Z\/OAlMdL4FU9nq0HxcvXAafKPDV3akLcQReJAvybkjIPTUTPcu
5jo6N1kxFt3tX5GGWp0="]
```

var_dump says 128 chars but obviously that are more than 128 - why is that?

Comment: Check again if the output you have shown is actually generated by precisely the code you have shown.

Comment: you are right I was mixed it with another string (json encoded response from my web service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part beginning with `["zrAND` is not generated by the code that you have given, but by some code that is executed but not shown in your question.

`var_dump($param['sec1']);` only prints out `string(128) "zrAND6xJVREfTA6SMfp1k9C+UDzabPMse6Awd/1Vul+2AgHLBzoOc0T/VlbQSV6dVjy38d/3dkRDaNnG9tJjCvy3Bm/OccPKo2amJkEANTAWTvt+cPtgIZW42FWdntE="`

Answer (score 2):

Because [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding increases the length of the encoded information by roughly 33% -- to be precise, the encoded length is `ceil(encoded_bytes / 3) * 4`.

When encoding 95 bytes, you end up with 128 because 95 / 3 = 31.667 and rounding up we have 32 * 4 = 128. The assertion that there are more than 128 is wrong.

It is important to understand that these 128 characters are not "more random" than the 95 bytes you generated to begin with; they are simply *a different way to represent the same information*.

If you want 130 random bytes, then you should simply generate as many with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`. Encoding these bytes into a printable form with Base64 will take up 176 characters.

If you want 130 random printable characters (which frankly sounds quite dubious) then generate 98 random bytes and encode them.

Comment: Downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment.

Answer (score 1):

### The error

You misread the output: your posted output is the 128-length string twice and some other strings, each quoted and comma-separated.

The reason you only get a 128-string is that the base64-encoding of the 95 bytes given from openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(95) takes up 128 chars, so the substring cannot deliver more than that and has no effect.

### The solution

You solve it by using

```
openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(110).
```

110 characters base-64 encoded result in 128 chars, so you can get the desired string length.

Comment: The output is a bad copy/paste from an array of 128-length Base64-encoded strings, for the purposes of the discussion we can assume that only the first string was ever given. Also, what's so special about 110?

Comment: 110 bytes result in 148 chars, not 128. And the last of these chars will always be `=`, so the random part is actually 147 chars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting

```
string(128) "mCtlWoWT6Dsy3QQyeH09Nm0oipxtnsG1zBDnCfNerCTyu6qfPtLxikPIff2vVbOMDhgt/QhclOAh5XR/L7rD0VOkRUYd3o3GtjJotO40RYvLZHrvO96XBdgAUvI8Mxc="
```

Count is 128.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this function

```
function getRandomString($length) {
    $res = '';
    do {
        $res .= md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
    } while (strlen($res) < $length);
    return substr($res, 0, $length);
}
```

Comment: -1 doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: Question was "I want a 130 chars random string".

Comment: @Pavel: Not my downvote, but this code will produce low quality randomness, useless for crypto purposes. Contrast this with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` which is the highest quality randomness you can get in standard PHP.

Comment: @Jon, Author didn't say that he really needs high-quality randomness, he didn't explain his goal. This question is so simple, so I do not think, that author trying to do something complicated, for example with encryption. I think he needs just random string and my solution, which generates printable symbols might be good enough for him and may be the most convenient. But maybe I am wrong. My point is, sometimes people ask their questions in confusing way, and sometimes they need simpler answer that you think.

Comment: @Pavel: He didn't say, but his example was *already* using high-quality randomness. Downgrading the quality without even a comment about it does not look right to me. It's fine to downgrade if you ask first or if you make it very clear that you are doing so.

Comment: @Jon, when I started using PHP, long time ago, during some time I used ereg_replace(), because I didn't know about str_replace() ;)